# How did Virginia jump from bullet trains when it slowed down?

Tags: plot-explanation, entrapment

In *Entrapment (1999)*, At Pudu Train station, Officials are ready to arrest Virginia, so she somehow step into the train & escapes. so officials gone to next stop to catch her but Robert still waiting at station. but again she arrives at same station instead of next stop.

> Robert: How did you do it?
>
> Virginia: I **jumped trains** mid-station. When the train slowed down It
>   was perfect.

Comment: It appears to be just a plot device to explain away how she returned right away. It also makes use of the "It was perfect" motif in the movie. It was apparently too trivial to make into its own scene.

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson I posted very detailed question & it also got answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It wasn't a bullet train.

It's a standard commuter train similar to subway trains around the world. These tend to go at relatively slow speeds.

[image]

What she is saying is that **between stations** she jumped from her original train  to one going the other way when the *both* slowed down to pass one another. Dangerous but she's a skilled athlete and gymnast..and she's suitably motivated to escape.

So, she ended back up at Pudu station. You might notice that the second train she was on pulls out of the station revealing here presence to Mac.